# How to keep text with different fontsize responsive

Tags: responsive-design

I am trying to display some text with different fontsizes over an fullwidth image.
However as soon as my browserwindow gets smaller my text collapses and my headline gets mixed up with my subline.
How can i write my css so that my text stays in proportion when ever it is displayed in a smaller size window.

```
   .wrap {
    max-width:100%;
    min-width:280px;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}
.wrap img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;

}
.caption {
    position:absolute;
top:5px;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:10px;
    overflow:auto;
}
.caption-inner {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.caption-content {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;

}
.headerposition {
        color:#ffffff;
    font-size:375%;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        position:absolute;
        left:21%;
        bottom:15%;
        top:29%

}
.subheaderposition {
        color:#ffffff;
    font-size:140%;
        position:absolute;
        left:21%;
        bottom:15%;
        top:45%;

}


.caption-content p {
        font-family: Century Gothic,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #ffffff;
        margin:0 50px;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
        padding:10px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a media query and have the font size accordingly

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {

      .subheaderposition {
        color:#ffffff;
    font-size:180%;
        position:absolute;
        left:21%;
        bottom:15%;
        top:45%;

}

}
```

Comment: In my css sheet i replaced my .subheaderposition class by your mediaquery. Now my fontsize is black, not positioned and has no header fontstyle....am i missing something?

Comment: Ya add your respective  styles in the query I was giving an example.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the **Font-Size in em** like this,

```
          body { font-size: 2em; }
```

Comment: I tried em but still when i make my browser window smaller the text collapses